# Webhooks for Zapier

Tags: zapier

I am having some trouble using the webhooks Zap with another program called FileStage. I have the Catch Hook and Get enabled. I've been able to do this on one Zap but when I duplicated it (because I need more than 3 paths) it no longer works on the duplicated zaps. I also tested this through the sample data and it worked file, it's just not running with new data.
Any help that you can lend would be appreciated as it helps us streamline our workflow to ensure nothing's missed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've been able to do this on one Zap but when I duplicated it (because I need more than 3 paths) it no longer works on the duplicated zaps)

Each duplicated zap gets its own Webhook Url, so you'll need to set up multiple outgoing webhooks in FileStage.